# Errors from building a one hidden neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm currently building my 3-4-1 neural network from scratch using numpy (I avoided using keras and tensorflow for the purpose of learning and trying to demonstrate my knowledge instead of using pre-built libraries to do all the work), the problems I find when I run the program are:
1/ getting "nan" values after a certain number of iterations in the "updated" weights, lowering the learning rate only delays the problem and doesn't solve it.
2/ the second problem is the very low predicting accuracy.
I would like to know what causes these bugs on my program and would appreciate any help.
here is the code:

```
# Import our dependencies
from numpy import exp, array, random, dot, ones_like, where

# Create our Artificial Neural Network class
class ArtificialNeuralNetwork():

    # initializing the class
    def __init__(self):

        # generating the same synaptic weights every time the program runs
        random.seed(1)

        # synaptic weights (3 × 4 Matrix) of the hidden layer 
        self.w_ij = 2 * random.rand(3, 4) - 1

        # synaptic weights (4 × 1 Matrix) of the output layer
        self.w_jk = 2 * random.rand(4, 1) - 1

    def LeakyReLU(self, x):

        # The Leaky ReLU (short for Rectified Linear Unit) activation function will be applied to the inputs of the hidden layer
        # The activation function will return the same value of x if x is positive
        # while it will multiply the negative values of x by the alpha parameter
        # we used in this example the Leaky ReLU instead of the standard ReLU activation function to avoid the dying ReLU problem

        return where(x > 0, x, x * 0.01)

    def LeakyReLUDerivative(self, x, α = 0.01):

        # The Leaky ReLU Derivative will return 1 for every positive value in the x array 
        # while returning the value of the parameter alpha for every negative value

        x[x > 0] = 1 # returns 1 for every positive value in the x array 

        x[x <= 0] = α # returns α for every negative value in the x array

        return x

    def Sigmoid(self, x):

        # The Sigmoid activation function will turn every input value into probabilities between 0 and 1
        # the probabilistic values help us assert which class x belongs to

        return 1 / (1 + exp(-x))

    def SigmoidDerivative(self, x):

        # The derivative of the Sigmoid activation function will be used to calculate the gradient during the backpropagation process
        # and help optimize the random starting synaptic weights

        return x * (1 - x)

    def train(self, x, y, learning_rate, iterations):

        # x: training set of data
        # y: the actual output of the training data

        for i in range(iterations):

            z_ij = dot(x, self.w_ij) # the dot product of the weights of the hidden layer and the inputs
            a_ij = self.LeakyReLU(z_ij) # using the Leaky ReLU activation function to introduce non-linearity to our Neural Network

            z_jk = dot(a_ij, self.w_jk) # the same precedent process will be applied to find the last input of the output layer
            a_jk = self.Sigmoid(z_jk) # this time the Sigmoid activation function will be used instead of Leaky ReLU 

            dl_jk = -y/a_jk + (1 - y)/(1 - a_jk) # calculating the derivative of the cross entropy loss wrt output
            da_jk = self.SigmoidDerivative(a_jk) # calculating the derivative of the Sigmoid activation function wrt the input (before activation) of the output layer
            dz_jk = a_ij # calculating the derivative of the inputs of the hidden layer (before activation) wrt weights of the output layer

            dl_ij = dot(da_jk * dl_jk, self.w_jk.T) # calculating the derivative of the cross entropy loss wrt activated input of the hidden layer
                                                # to do so we multiply the derivative of the cross entropy loss wrt output by the derivative of the Sigmoid activation function wrt the input (before activation) of the output layer by the derivative of the inputs of the hidden layer (before activation) wrt weights of the output layer 
            da_ij = self.LeakyReLUDerivative(z_ij) # calculating the derivative of the Leaky ReLU activation function wrt the inputs of the hidden layer (before activation)
            dz_ij = x # calculating the derivative of the inputs of the hidden layer (before activation) wrt weights of the hidden layer

            # calculating the gradient using the chain rule
            gradient_ij = dot(dz_ij.T , dl_ij * da_ij)
            gradient_jk = dot(dz_jk.T , dl_jk * da_jk)

            # calculating the new optimal weights
            self.w_ij = self.w_ij - learning_rate * gradient_ij 
            self.w_jk = self.w_jk - learning_rate * gradient_jk

    def predict(self, inputs):

        # predicting the class of the input data after weights optimization

        output_from_layer1 = self.LeakyReLU(dot(inputs, self.w_ij)) # the output of the hidden layer

        output_from_layer2 = self.Sigmoid(dot(output_from_layer1, self.w_jk)) # the output of the output layer

        return output_from_layer1, output_from_layer2

    # the function will print the initial starting weights before training
    def SynapticWeights(self):

        print("Layer 1 (4 neurons, each with 3 inputs): ")

        print("w_ij: ", self.w_ij)

        print("Layer 2 (1 neuron, with 4 inputs): ")

        print("w_jk: ", self.w_jk)


def main():

    ANN = ArtificialNeuralNetwork()

    ANN.SynapticWeights()

    # the training inputs 
    x = array([[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]])

    # the training outputs
    y = array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]]).T

    ANN.train(x, y, 1, 10000)

    # Printing the new synaptic weights after training
    print("New synaptic weights after training: ")
    print("w_ij: ", ANN.w_ij)
    print("w_jk: ", ANN.w_jk)

    # Our prediction after feeding the ANN with new set of data
    print("Considering new situation [1, 1, 0] -> ?: ")
    print(ANN.predict(array([[1, 1, 0]])))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more about the problem? I don't get any Nan FYI

Comment: Hi Umang Gupta thanks for the quick response, the program gives nan values as its updated weights if the number of iterations exceeds a certain limit, i edited the code right now the following program will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I changed a few things. (Disclaimer: I didn't check the correctness of the code)

1. Weight initialization: initialize to much smaller weights.

   ```
   # synaptic weights (3 × 4 Matrix) of the hidden layer
   self.w_ij = (2 * random.rand(3, 4) - 1)*0.1

   # synaptic weights (4 × 1 Matrix) of the output layer
   self.w_jk = (2 * random.rand(4, 1) - 1)*0.1
   ```

Weight initialization really matter.

2. I reduced the learning rate to 0.1.

   ```
   ANN.train(x, y, .1, 500000)
   ```
3. I see the neural network perfectly fitting your data and not giving Nan even after 500,000 iterations.

   ```
   print(ANN.predict(array([[0, 0, 1],
                            [0, 1, 1],
                            [1, 0, 1],
                            [0, 1, 0],
                            [1, 0, 0],
                            [1, 1, 1],
                            [0, 0, 0]])))
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the help Umang Gupta I really appreciate the effort you put to solve my problem, when passing the training data (again) I found out that my data was actually fit as you mentioned except the last [0, 0, 0] array where the input gives an output of 0.5 even after updating the weights. which might probably explain the moderate accuracy of my nn when fed with an input that it never saw.

Comment: @BlgKhalil It might be that the neural network can not fit better than this. You can increase the parameters and see if it fits. Also, if you think this sufficiently answers your problem, please accept and/or upvote :)

Comment: Definitely going to do it for the time you sacrificed for my coding problem :)